# Make bash expand Wildcard in script command?

Tags: linux, bash

My script receives a wildcard as a parameter and I need to apply the `find` command on it. The problem is that if I don't quote the parameter, shell expands it relative to the current directory, but if I do, the `find` command doesn't expand it at all.

My code currently looks like this :

```
find /bin/"$1"
```

and `$1` is `*sh*`
If I run it as `/bin/*sh*` in terminal, it works as intended.

Answer (score 3):

The `-name` test is what expands wildcards when you use `find`. Try this:

```
find /bin/ -name "$1"
```

Comment: Thanks ! Any particular reason why this gives the results in a different order?

Comment: The shell sorts glob results but `find` doesn't do any sorting. That lets it print results as soon as it finds each file rather than waiting until the end. You'll need a manual `| sort` or the like if you want the file names in a particular order.